Gaussian measure measurability
I want to use the transition probability theory to prove the existence of a measure on a product space : I have two spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and for each $\omega \in \Omega$ i have another probability space $(A,\mathfrak{B},\mu_{\varrho_{\omega}})$ . my question is , knowing that for each $\omega$ the measure $\mu_{\varrho_{\omega}}$ is a gaussian measure and that $\varrho_{\omega}$ is measurable with respect to $\omega$ , can i say that for each $T \in \mathfrak{B}$ the function $$X:\omega \mapsto \mu_{\varrho_{\omega}}(T)$$ is measurable or not . And thank you very much !
Here $A$ is an infinite Dimensional Space,$\varrho_{\omega}$ is the covariance kernel defined as in the the comments.

I’m confused. What is $\mu_{\rho_\omega}$? What is $\rho_\omega$? Is the latter also a measure? What does it mean for $\rho_\omega$ to be measurable?

@DavidGao , For each $\omega \in  \Omega$ ,$\mu_{\varrho_{\omega}}$ is a gaussian measure on $A$, $\varrho_{\omega}$ is the covariance kernel of the Gaussian measure In fact we have that $$\int_{A}e^{i<x,\psi>}\mu_{\varrho_{\omega}}(dx)=e^{-1/2(\psi,\varrho_{\omega}}\psi$$. and i mean that we know that $$\omega \mapsto \varrho_{\omega}$$ is measurable function. and thanj very much!

I presume you meant $A = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\rho_\omega$ are all $n \times n$ matrices then? If so, you should edit your question and put all these information (including your reply to me) in there.

Actually $A$ is an infinite Dimensional space, i jus want to know how to, prove measurability of the function $X$ mentioned above and thnx @DavidGao
